# Avoid premature wrap on whitespace?

Tags: css

My site's `header` section contains a list which is supposed to wrap on smaller screens

But at certain screen sizes, a wrap occurs (= the height of the header section doubles) *before* the first list item is moved to the second line. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour and make sure the `header`'s height only increases when there actually is a list item displayed on the second line?

```css
header > nav > ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    hyphens: none;
    margin: 0;
}

header > nav > ul > li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> ...  </li>
                <li> ...  </li>
                <li> ...  </li>
                <li> ...  </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>...</main>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You'll need to post code that demonstrates the issue. There are better ways these days to style a menu these days too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flexbox` and `flex-wrap`:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use flexbox, you can use media queries to adjust the CSS styling of the element based on the screen size:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    /* adjusted styles */
  }
}
```

If you want to stop list items from wrapping individually, you can set `white-space: nowrap;` on the list item.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, `flexbox` did not change the display behaviour. I already use `@media` for mobile screen sizes, the issue affects mid-size displays (e.g. iPads in portrait orientation), and the generic CSS styling works well for them (except for the annoying menu effect described above).

Comment: Sorry – your suggestion worked! Thank you!